# Why is the induced map between pullbacks (of inclusions) by a right fibration a deformation retract?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a simplicial set.  Let $X\to \Delta^n$ be a right fibration (has the right lifting property with respect to right horn inclusions), and let $$\Delta^{\{n-i\}}\hookrightarrow \Delta^{\{n-i,\dots, n\}}\hookrightarrow \Delta^n$$ (for a fixed $i: 0\leq i\leq n$) be the obvious inclusion maps.

Then why is the induced map:

$$X\times_{\Delta^n} \Delta^{\{n-i\}} \hookrightarrow X\times_{\Delta^n}\Delta^{\{n-i,\dots, n\}}$$

a deformation retract?  It's not like we can apply Whitehead's theorem, since $\Delta^n$ is not a Kan complex in general.

(This is from the end of the proof of proposition 2.2.3.1 of [HTT](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608040v4).  The statement should be true out of the context in the book with the hypotheses I've given, but if not, there's the source.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In topology, if a map $Y\to B$ is some sort of fibration then you would think that $B$ being equivalent to a subspace $A$ would imply that $Y$ is equivalent to $Y_A=Y\times_BA$. If fibration means Serre fibration and equivalent means weakly, then you might want to use homotopy groups and the Whitehead Theorem. But what if we try to prove directly that a deformation retraction of $B$ to $A$ would yield a deformation retraction of $Y$ to $Y_A$? Then we will want to assume that $Y\to B$ has the 'relative homotopy lifting property' for the pair $(Y,Y_A)$, that is, the right lifting property with respect to the inclusion $Y\times 0\cup Y_A\times I\to Y\times I$.

I suppose that this it how it is in what you are looking at:  Any right fibration of simplicial sets has the RLP w.r.t. $K\times \lbrace 1\rbrace \cup L\times \Delta^1\to K\times \Delta^1$ for every $L\subset K$ (but not w.r.t. $K\times \lbrace 0\rbrace \cup L\times \Delta^1\to K\times \Delta^1$), and this is good for lifting the sort of deformation retraction that exists from a simplex to its zeroth vertex.

Something like that.

Comment: Dear Tom, would you mind clarifying the end a bit?  I'm still a bit lost on how to actually prove the claim.

Comment: In particular, why is there a deformation retraction from the point to the simplex. I mean, it's a trivial cofibration, but I thought that $\Delta^n$ is only weakly contractible but not contractible. If there is a deformation retraction onto the initial vertex, that says it is contractible.  

Comment: Harry, I'm not sure how you are using the word 'contractible' for simplicial sets. And, come to think of it, I'm not sure how I would use it. But Lurie is definitely asserting that the inclusion of that vertex into that i-simplex 'is a deformation retract', because you can take X to be the n-simplex.

Note that, even though $\Delta^n$ is not fibrant, there is a map $\Delta^n\times \Delta^1\to\Delta^n$ that can be called a homotopy relating the identity to a constant map to a vertex. First or last vertex dictates which end of the homotopy the identity is at.

Comment: @Tom, I think you need to compose two such homotopies if your vertex is neither the first nor the last (a self-map of $\Delta^n$ is a monotone map on the set of vertices, and there is a unique homotopy from one monotone map f to another g as you describe iff $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all x).

Comment: @Tyler: Yes. I did not make that explicit because I was coming up against the length limit for a comment.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.

Comment: Such an orgy of politeness! No apology necessary.

Comment: Dear Tom, I've been struggling with the proof of this fact for a while now.  Is there any chance you could sketch it?  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: To clarify, I mean the statement in the original question.  I constructed the deformation retract from comment #3 alright.

Comment: Well, I asked it as a separate question.  Here's the link if you want to answer it.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30224/proof-sketch-the-pullback-of-the-inclusion-of-the-0th-vertex-into-the-standard-n